# If I delete a user on macos, what happens to folders they set to 'no access' for everyone?

Tags: macos, permission

I'm on a brand new install of High Sierra.  I created a temporary admin user (named 'bean') while setting up the system.  Using 'bean' (admin), I ran Migration Assistant, and migrated the 2 users ("Scott", "Apple") in from my old High Sierra, along with all their data/settings/etc (everything Migration Assistant offered).  It was an internal SSD to other internal SSD, same laptop, migration. That much data took a few hours.  Afterwards, I switched into user "Scott" (admin) and went to delete the temporary "bean" user.  However, I discover that within the migration time, random pre-existing folders all over my drives had permissions changed. 'bean' has been added, set as 'read and write', and 'everyone' is now set to 'no access'.

I never learned how to use "sharing & permissions" correctly, so I don't know how/why this happened or how to fix it.  My first thought...

**If I delete the temporary user, what happens to all these "no access" folders that they control?**

[image: sample get info of modified permissions]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us some file paths of these random folders, and show us the permissions that you see? Are these on external drives?

Comment: It got into both external and internal drives, file storage and OS drives, and auto backups of all of them.  Oops, still editing.

Comment: continued: Sample internal path: MojaveSSD/Users/Apple/Documents, set to temporary user as read and write, and everyone is set to no access. (but folder obviously belongs to user "Apple".)  Sample external path: MacintoshHDDi/ApolloDVD, set the same as the other one.  Just realized I don't know how to add pics here...

Comment: You can add pictures directly to the question by editing it.

Comment: Anyway, assume you have "ignore ownership" checked for the external drives. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466078/user-files-ownership-anomalies-on-macos-14-0

Comment: Is the screenshot from a folder on the drive you boot from, or from another drive?

Comment: My storage drive,,and it's auto-backup, are NOT checked "ignore ownership".  Should I check them?  I have a few different OS drives I boot. The screen shot is from one of them.

Comment: So, "bean" is the temporary account, and "apple" is what you're logged in as? And you can't access your own Documents folder? You may need to reset user permissions, which you have to do from Terminal in Recovery boot. (I'm trying to find instructions, but the procedure has changed in new OSes.)

Comment: Also: do you have a backup?

Comment: Yes, "bean" is temporary account.  No, the "apple" account is a user on a Mojave system that's not the active system right now.  I'm yet another user on another (High Sierra) system that IS active right now. Currently, I have 3 OS volumes, and 3 more that are clones of the OS volumes.  If I booted the Mojave drive, and logged into "Apple", I believe you are correct, and "Apple" wouldn't have access to it's own folder(s).  I did some more googling, and I'm starting to see reults about Migration Aassistant messing up permissions.  I'm too tired to concentrate on those tuntil tomorrrow.

Comment: Ran out of space.  I do have backups, but they were attached, and also had permissions modified.  Just added a pic of "Apple"'s user folder. Almost everything is "no access", unless you are "bean" who has read and write.

Answer (score 3):

You say you're on High Sierra, but that drive is named Mojave. If you boot to different OSes on different drives, permissions will not be synced between them, each will have its own idea of what belongs to who - and that may be based on the account's *number* rather than its name. The first account is always 501, the next 502, etc. If you've ever added & removed accounts, then the numbering on each OS may be different.

If, however, 'apple' is an admin [on at least one of the OSes, hopefully all] then that can always be used to change permissions, so you won't get locked out so long as you can log into an admin account. It's often sensible to set any non-boot drives to ignore ownership - if you have no security concerns between the individual users, i.e. they're all actually you.

e.g from this
[image]

to this
[image]

You can add any individual user, or a group & set what perms they are allowed, simply by unlocking the padlock bottom right, & selecting another user or group. You can also propagate this new permission down the entire depth of the folder using the gear icon.

Comment: It's just me on all accounts.  Every OS has an "apple", and my daily use OS has "apple" AND "scott".  All "apple" and "scott" are always admin. "bean" was admin only a few hours until I migrated "apple" and "scott" into the same system. I dropped "bean" to 'standard' when I found all the changes, but I didn't know if it was safe to remove him altogether. I switch back and forth between multiple High Sierras, and a Mojave.  I have no ownership issues between them.  The only potentially shared files are on a drive with no OS, and I never use permissions anywhere,

Comment: That seems to explain it - & sounds like it *is* down the the account *number*. If 'apple' & 'scott' were existing accounts on one OS, then they were 501 & 502. If 'bean' was the first account on the new OS… that's your 501. There is a way to re-align those numbers, but I think it would be best asked as a new question rather than an adjunct to this one.

Comment: Your ignore ownership solution sounds good for the storage drives.  1.  You never answered if I should check the "ignore ownership" box on those?  2.  What level do I do the permission changes on those, the top of each (the drive?)?  3.  I see you added "admin", but my add option is "administrators" (there is no "admin"), is that the correct choice?  4. I have to find a different solution for the OS drives, correct?

Comment: If safe, I am going to delete "bean", and his number won't be an issue.

Comment: I was sure i'd covered 'ignore ownership'. You can apply it to any drive you're not currently booted from, if that later becomes a boot drive the option will just vanish, to reappear next time it's not the OS. It covers the entire volume. Admin, staff, administrator, all equivalent. Any group so long as you're a member of it. Deleting bean won't renumber the accounts, just leave 501 without an actual attendent account.

Comment: Sorry guys, I guess I was a little too frustrated and I left too much out of my question.  I revised it now.  Also, I didn't even notice THREE of you were helping at once. I'll re-read all replies and straighten it out in my head.  I sincerely appreciate all the help.

Comment: Doesn't Migration Assistant adjust all the account numbers on the target disk?

Comment: Not if there's an account already made before you migrate. [Been there, done that, ripped up the t-shirt]

Comment: @Tetujin short answer:  I _had to_ make the temporary 'bean' account so I could test the new High Serra install for a specific problem.  Also, had I migrated DURING install/setup instead, I have 750G to migrate, and it would take ~6 hours.  6 hour waits would ruin my ability to quickly test each installation for the other problem I mentioned.  UPDATE I turned on the 'ignore ownership' on my storage drive and it took an hour, but the result looks good,  so I'm doing it on the other storage drive now.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Storage drives fixed.  I want to fix the OS drives now, but I'm still confused.  I never knew about account numbers until today, so I don't understand the discussion of how they affect my options to fix the OS drives.  If I delete the 'bean' account, do his permissions settings vanish from all folders, or do they live on without him?  NEXT, regarding your answer to have my admin account modify permissions by adding a group (I would use "administrators"), can you confirm I do this at the very top level of each OS drive (the volume?). These are big changes so I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Tetsujin  I realized I should also ask, do I need to be booted into each OS drive to fix the permissions, or can I do them all from anywhere, as long as I am an admin?

Comment: As in my opening paragraph. You need to do it from each OS.

Comment: I logged into 2 systems, both admins in each, get-info at top level, added "administrators" and got "the operation can't be completed because you don't have the necessary permission".  double-checked, both users are admin in both systems.  first system has no other users.  second system has 'bean' user, but that is set to standard, not admin.  get-info picture added to post.  not sure what's next.  NEXT  installed band new mojave system yesterday, nothing migrated. 'bean. account is somehow already in those folders, taking permissions again.  thanks

Comment: very odd. if I'm in High Sierra system, just looking at user folders in Mojave system, it shows 'bean' r&w on the permissions.  if I boot into Mojave system, look at exact same folders, now 'bean' is gone and permissions are normal.

Comment: You cannot change perms on the root level of a drive - nor was that any part of my instructions. All your OSes are independent, they don't know anything about each other. I really can't keep track of what you've done, now. Too many confusing reports.

Comment: I haven't been able to do anything except erase my Mojave system drive, and install a new Mojave system in it's place.  Nothing was migrated or copied into new Mojave.  My OSs are supposed to be independent, but 'bean' shows up in permissions on the brand new Mojave.  I 100% agree it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to solve this, with the help of a backup copy of the pre-migration New High Sierra system (still has 'bean' though).

There's 3 systems:
Original High Sierra, New High Sierra (pre-migration), and I'm setting-aside the previous New High Sierra (post-migration) for now.

I figured out how to look up the User IDs in SystemPreferences>Users&Groups and:

Old System had "Scott" 501 and "Apple" 502.
New System has "bean" 501.  Ignoring the set-aside system.

I went into the New System and added new users: 502, 503, 504, and 505 (up to 505 just to be careful).  Then I deleted users "bean" 501, 502, 503, and 504, leaving 505 as the only account.

Still in the New System, I ran Migration Assistant, and imported "Scott" 501 and all data/settings (except "Apple"). "Scott" retained User ID 501 after the migration. Then I deleted user 505. I went back into Migration Assistant and imported "Apple" 502. "Apple" likewise retained User ID 502 after migration.

Then I deleted the **set-aside** previous post-migration New System (all 3 users, including "bean").  I didn't want it to conflict with the new post-migration system.

The New (post-migration) system has all permissions in-line with "Scott" and "Apple" ownership.  The external drives that were affected, now have their folder permissions in-line with "Scott" and "Apple" as well. I'm not sure if the external changes reverted when "bean" 501 was deleted from the New System, or when I deleted the entire previous System I had set-aside (also with "bean" 501 in it).

Regardless, 'bean' 501 has been deleted, permissions now belong to "Scott" 501, both in-system and in external drives.

If someone doesn't have a saved copy of the destination system, I would suggest using a clean install, and importing their "Scott" 501 with the Setup Assistant during install/setup, thus avoiding creation of a new account that could start the problem all over again.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. If you don't use the old system any longer, a `chown -R ...` to assign uids probably would have worked as well.